# Iterate through JSON with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get the color names and hex values from some json data that I am retrieving from an external source.  I created a jsfiddle to work through it but I am doing something fundamentally wrong because I don't even get to alert('hi');
Ideally I would like a list of the three color names with hex value beside it:
Eg.

- Brilliant Black - #000000
- Ice Silver Metallic - #C3C3C3
- Scuba Blue Metallic - #2E3F59

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Thread7/vp01m13x/2/

HTML:

```
<ul id="groups">
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
jsonval = '[{"category":"Exterior","options":[{"id":"200421460","name":"Brilliant Black","colorChips":{"primary":{"hex":"000000"}}},{"id":"200421466","name":"Ice Silver Metallic","colorChips":{"primary":{"hex":"C3C3C3"}}},{"id":"200421462","name":"Scuba Blue Metallic","colorChips":{"primary":{"hex":"2E3F59"}}}]}]';
var cardata = JSON.parse(jsonval);
$.each(cardata.options, function(o, valo) {
  alert('hi');
  $('<li>' + valo + '</li>').appendTo($grouplist);
});
```

Comment: @Martin: Click the gear in the upper-right of the 'JavaScript' box.

Comment: @Martin It's selected in the FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS setting in the fiddle

Comment: @RayonDabre: The OP *did* add jQuery to their fiddle.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, Oops..I read it wrong...

Comment: What's `$grouplist`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cardata.options` doesn't exist because `cardata` is an *array* containing a single element, an object.

Then inside your `$.each`, `valo` will be an *object*.  You'll need to use `valo.id`, `valo.name`, etc.

```
$.each(cardata[0].options, function(o, valo) {
    console.log(valo.id);
});
```

Here's an updated version of your demo:

```js
var jsonval = '[{"category":"Exterior","options":[{"id":"200421460","name":"Brilliant Black","colorChips":{"primary":{"hex":"000000"}}},{"id":"200421466","name":"Ice Silver Metallic","colorChips":{"primary":{"hex":"C3C3C3"}}},{"id":"200421462","name":"Scuba Blue Metallic","colorChips":{"primary":{"hex":"2E3F59"}}}]}]';

var $grouplist = $('#groups');

var cardata = JSON.parse(jsonval);
$.each(cardata[0].options, function(o, valo) {
  $('<li style="color:#' + valo.colorChips.primary.hex + ';">' + valo.name + '</li>').appendTo($grouplist);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="groups"></ul>
```

Comment: Is it a typo or something ?

Comment: @RayonDabre: Is what a typo?

Comment: @RayonDabre: Ah, yes.  Forgot the `]`.  My bad, didn't notice that.

Comment: Aah it happens...As input `json` is there, you can post executable snippet :)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a small problem with your JSON string. You have it wrapped in an array. You are trying to iterate `cardata.options` - which doesn't exist.

#### Two ways to fix this:

1. Either remove the outer array (the `[` and `]` outside your string)
2. Iterate over `cardata[0].options`

#### Still not behaving, yet...

So it's still not working in your fiddle. This is because of a reference to `$grouplist` which (at least in the [fiddle linked in the question](https://jsfiddle.net/Thread7/vp01m13x/2/)), does not exist.

Either remove the line referencing it, or you can add `var $grouplist = $('ul');` at the top of the script.

Then it will work:

[image]

#### For future reference

You can easily test JSON strings out by popping that string into any popular web browser's debugging tools:

[image]